# How do I keep the spaces in my dashed line from changing when I modify the line length in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, stroke, illustrator-effects

Using Adobe Illustrator CS6, I drew a line and clicked the "Dashed Line" option in the stroke palette.

When I change the length of the dashed line, by grabbing an endpoint and moving it or clipping it, the size of the gaps and dashes in the line change. I don't want that to happen. I checked the various boxes in the Transform options but nothing helps.

How do I keep the dashes and gaps consistent in a dashed line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the "Preserve exact dash and gap lengths" option in the Stroke Panel. It's the left-most of a pair of illustrated buttons, just to the right of the "Dashed Line" checkbox.

[image: Preserve dash length]

Comment: That did it! I've used this program since ver. 8 and can't believe some of the tools and tricks that I've missed that are right under my nose... THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

In the Transform Palette side menu, turn off Scale Strokes & Effects.

You can also turn it off in the Preferences.
Hit Command + K and uncheck it in the General tab.

Comment: I do have "Scale Strokes & Effects" unchecked. The size of gaps and dashes still change.

Comment: hmm, that should have fixed it. Are there any other effects applied to the line?

Comment: I checked the appearance palette and don't see anything else added to the line other than stroke.